# How to use play on linux to play games that don't require install

Tags: 18.04, lubuntu, playonlinux

I play a lot of rpgm games and a lot of them are just archived with no install required. How do I run such games with play on linux?

Comment: Why don't you try to run them with Wine alone?

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia Because I heard wine is less efficient than Play on Linux and I get script lag sometimes? It's also easier to have everything in 1 easily organized place than dig through directories every time I want to play a game due to wines awful methods of directory sorting. Steam's Proton doesn't seem to work with external programs either.

Comment: PlayonLinux is just an utility that uses Wine, it does nothing without it. It's convenient because it can create containers for different apps and use different Wine versions that it conveniently downloads and installs in those different containers. It also includes scripts for additional downloads needed for some software. It is NOT designed for software that isn't meant to be installed though. And Wine has nothing to do with "directory sorting". You're very much confused. Again, try just running with Wine (and check the software status in WineHQ first, anything below Gold is not worth it).

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia think you misinterpreted my statement. When I install something through wine it forcibly shoves it into /home/USERNAME/windows games which quickly becomes a massive mess of a directory.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia because for me everything needs to be neatly organized and having some stuff shoved in a stupidly disorganized directory and other stuff neat further increases my frustration over it. Hence why I like launchers where it's easy to keep track of everything. Also for the last time I do not want to launch directly through wine because digging through directories is a headache period. Finally if you ask me just saying to launch directly through wine is irrelevant as that is not what I asked.

Comment: continued from the last comment. In the first place file managers are irritating because the only way to sort things is to make another directory or tag them in some way. As such you end up digging through a ton of directories or having a huge mess.

Comment: You're  still not getting it. If the software you want just runs,  by double click, for example,  it can be anywhere you want,  in any folder you like. Why, again, are you insisting on PoL? That's only for software that requires installation.

Comment: Because I like having everything well organized and in 1 place. I found a solution through lutris anyways.

Comment: Again,  you can it organized anywhere you want and run the software from anywhere you want,  create shortcuts, etc. with Wine alone.

Comment: I'm done here we have a different definition of organized so we will clearly not see eye to eye.

Comment: We may have a different understanding but that's not the  problem. The problem is a nonsensical question. Bye.

Answer (score -1):

Install `winetricks` using:

```
sudo apt install winetricks
```

Open `winetricks` , select your default Wine prefix, then install the DLLs and components which are necessary for your specific game. After that, run your game with the following command:

```
wine ./game
```